# ¿Cómo evitar que el Adapter de un ListView vuelva a cargar al deslizar el scroll?

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

Tengo un `ScrollView` y un `Adapter` asociado, pero este `Adapter` se recarga cada vez que deslizo el `Scroll`.
¿Cómo podría solucionar esta situación?
De antemano gracias.

Este es el adaptador:

```
public class ListFacilitiesReviewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
String[] titulos;
String[] address;
String[] ratingF;
String[] review;
boolean imgLoad;
Map<Integer, String[]> imagenesReviews;
int[] imagenes;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public ListFacilitiesReviewsAdapter(Context context, String[] titulos, int[] imagenes, String[] address, String[] rating, String[] review, Map<Integer, String[]> imagenesReviews) {
    this.context = context;
    this.titulos = titulos;
    this.imagenes = imagenes;
    this.address = address;
    this.ratingF = rating;
    this.review = review;
    this.imagenesReviews = imagenesReviews;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return titulos.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtAddress;
    TextView lblReviewUser;
    ImageView imgImg;
    ImageView imgReview;
    RatingBar rating;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_formato_reviews, parent, false);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblDetListFacilityName);
        txtAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblDetListFacilityAddress);
        lblReviewUser = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblReviewUser);
        imgImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iconLista);
        imgReview = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgReview);
        rating = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingFacility);

        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        txtTitle.setText(titulos[position]);
        txtAddress.setText(address[position]);
        lblReviewUser.setText(review[position]);
        imgImg.setImageResource(imagenes[position]);
        rating.setRating(Float.valueOf(ratingF[position]));
    return itemView;
}
```

}

Este es el fragment en el cual tengo el scrollView

```
public class UserReviewsFragment extends Fragment {

public UserReviewsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_reviews, container, false);
    listFacilityUserReviews = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listFacilityUserReviews);

    final ReviewServiceImpl reviewService = new ReviewServiceImpl();
    try {
        facilityReviewService.getFacilityReviews("1").done(new DoneCallback<FacilityReviewDto>() {
            @Override
            public void onDone(FacilityReviewDto result) {

                if (result.getReviews().size() > 0) {

                    Map<Integer, String[]> datos = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();

                    titulo = new String[result.getReviews().size()];
                    rating = new String[result.getReviews().size()];
                    imagenes = new int[result.getReviews().size()];
                    address = new String[result.getReviews().size()];
                    review = new String[result.getReviews().size()];


                    for (int i = 0; i < result.getReviews().size(); i++) {
                        titulo[i] = result.getReviews().get(i).getFacility().getName();
                        titulo[i] = result.getReviews().get(i).getFacility().getName();
                        address[i] = result.getReviews().get(i).getFacility().getAddress();
                        rating[i] = result.getReviews().get(i).getFacility().getAverageRating();
                        review[i] = result.getReviews().get(i).getReview();
                        imagenes[i] = R.drawable.house1;

                        imagenesReviews = new String[result.getReviews().get(i).getMedias().size()];

                        if(imagenesReviews.length>0){
                            for(int ii =0 ;ii<result.getReviews().get(i).getMedias().size();ii++){
                                imagenesReviews[ii] = result.getReviews().get(i).getMedias().get(ii).getUrl();
                            }
                            datos.put(i,imagenesReviews);
                        }
                    }

                    adapter = new ListFacilitiesReviewsAdapter(getActivity(), titulo, imagenes, address, rating,review,datos,result.getReviews().size());
                    listFacilityUserReviews.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Puedes dejar el codigo de tu adaptador?

Comment: ok, actualizo la pregunta

Comment: ¿Puedes enseñar el código donde se encuentra tu ListView?

Comment: ¿Y a que te refieres con que "se recarga cada vez que deslizas el scroll"?

Comment: Por ejemplo cuando deslizo los items del scrollView hacia abajo o hacia arriba

Comment: No hace falta que cada pregunta que hagas pongas : "Android:" en el titulo, ni  "buen día" en el la descripción del problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que en tu metodo `getView` de tu adaptador falta un bloque de codigo importante

Cuando por primera vez se carga tu vista el valor del parametro `view` es nulo. Y creas el formato de tu custom listview. Cuando no es nulo, obtienes ya el formato antiguo, esto de ayudara a resolver tu error.

```
ViewHolderitem holder;
static class ViewHolderitem{
    TextView txtTitle;
}

View v= view;
if (v == null) {
     holder = new ViewHolderitem();
     v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_formato_reviews, parent, false);
         //aqui creas y buscas las id de tus textview, imagenes etc etc.
     holder.txtTitle = v.findViewById(R.id.lblDetListFacilityName);
     v.setTag(holder);
}else {
         //si no es nula, devuelves la que ta estaba asignada
      holder = (Holder) v.getTag();
}
    //aqui haces el tratamiento normal de los datos, asignas tus items y todo lo demas.
holder.txtTitle.setText("...");
return v;
```

**EDICION**

En la documentacion [Android ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) te explican que cuando deslizas tu listview llamas infinidad de veces al metodo `findViewById()` y esto puede ocacionar lentitud en tu lista y tambien buscar nuevamente los elementos y actualizarlos (tu error). ViewHolder como puedes ver guarda los componentes 1 sola vez y no hay necesidad de ir a buscarlos nuevamente a tu layout.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta sioesi, esa clase Holder, que deberia tener?

Comment: Ahi edite mi respuesta, debe tener los elementos visuales que tiene tu listview custom por ejemplo los textview, edittext, imagenes etc

Comment: Me gustaria ver tambien como es que cargas tu listview, como creas y cargas tu adaptador con los valores

Comment: En la preguna deje el codigo del adaptador en el cual asigno los valores

Comment: Si, ya lo verifique. Te deje un link de la documentacion de lo que te explique en mi respuesta. Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias  sioesi

Comment: Cualquier cosa me comentas @devjav

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49944/discussion-between-devjav-and-sioesi).